# Why is pango_layout_get_pixel_size slightly wrong on Ubuntu Linux in C

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk, pango

I'm experiencing a frustrating issue trying to draw text using Pango and Cairo libraries in C in a Gtk application running on Ubuntu Linux.

I'm creating a Pango layout and then drawing it at a given location which is determined by the size of the text as reported by pango_layout_get_pixel_size, but the size returned by that function is wrong in both width and height, especially in height. Here is my full code:

```
// Create a cairo context with which to draw
// Note that we already have a GtkDrawingArea widget m_pGtkDrawingArea
cairo_t *cr = gdk_cairo_create(m_pGtkDrawingArea->window);

// Text to draw
std::string szText("NO DATA AVAILABLE");

// Create the layout
PangoLayout *pLayout = gtk_widget_create_pango_layout(m_pGtkDrawingArea, szText.c_str());

// Set layout properties
pango_layout_set_alignment(pLayout, PANGO_ALIGN_LEFT);
pango_layout_set_width(pLayout, -1);

// The family to use
std::string szFontFamily("FreeSans");

// The font size to use
double dFontSize = 36.0;

// Format the font description string
char szFontDescription[32];
memset(&(szFontDescription[0]), 0, sizeof(szFontDescription));
snprintf(szFontDescription, sizeof(szFontDescription) - 1, "%s %.1f", szFontFamily.c_str(), dFontSize);

// Get a new pango font description
PangoFontDescription *pFontDescription = pango_font_description_from_string(szFontDescription);

// Set up the pango font description
pango_font_description_set_weight(pFontDescription, PANGO_WEIGHT_NORMAL);
pango_font_description_set_style(pFontDescription, PANGO_STYLE_NORMAL);
pango_font_description_set_variant(pFontDescription, PANGO_VARIANT_NORMAL);
pango_font_description_set_stretch(pFontDescription, PANGO_STRETCH_NORMAL);

// Set this as the pango font description on the layout
pango_layout_set_font_description(pLayout, pFontDescription);

// Use auto direction
pango_layout_set_auto_dir(pLayout, TRUE);

// Get the pixel size of this text - this reports a size of 481x54 pixels
int iPixelWidth = 0, iPixelHeight = 0;
pango_layout_get_pixel_size(pLayout, &iPixelWidth, &iPixelHeight);

// Calculate the text location based on iPixelWidth and iPixelHeight
double dTextLocX = ...;
double dTextLocY = ...;

// Set up the cairo context for drawing the text
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
cairo_set_antialias(cr, CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_BEST);

// Move into place
cairo_move_to(cr, dTextLocX, dTextLocY);

// Draw the layout
pango_cairo_show_layout(cr, pLayout);

//
// pango_layout_get_pixel_size() reported a size of 481x54 pixels,
// but the actual size when drawn is 478x37 pixels!
//

//
// Clean up...
//
```

So, as described at the bottom of the above code, the pango_layout_get_pixel_size function reports a size of 481x54 pixels, but the size of the text on the screen is actually 478x37 pixels.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get the actual correct pixel size?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text you are displaying (`"NO DATA AVAILABLE"`) is all-caps, and consequently has no descenders (letters which are partly below the baseline, like j, p and q.) Normally, when you measure the extent of a text box, you include room for the descenders whether or not they are present; otherwise, you will see odd artifacts such as inconsistent line separation depending on whether or not a given line has a descender.

Pango provides APIs which return both the *logical* extent (which includes the full height of the font) and the *ink* extent (which is the bounding box of the inked part of the image). I suspect you are looking for the ink extent.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you!